# MySQL (# of Products in Category) COUNT() w/ LEFT JOIN & ON 2 Tables

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I am trying to resolve getting a count of all products in each category. Products are uniquely identified by **PRODUCT_ID**. The **PRD_PRODUCTS** table does not have a CATEGORY_ID field, but all products are joined in a join table **PRD_CATEGORIES** on PRODUCT_ID and CATEGORY_ID.

**I have 2 tables:**

PRD_PRODUCTS and PRD_CATEGORIES.

```
PRD_PRODUCTS
------------
PRODUCT_ID  - varchar(64)
TITLE - varchar(64)

PRD_CATEGORIES
--------------
CATEGORY_ID - varchar(64)
PRODUCT_ID - varchar(64)
TITLE - varchar(64)
```

**Example data:**
PRODUCT_ID: *5e313ec3bf7b967569eec196b4693829 (unique ID assigned to each product)*
TITLE: *Product Name One (product name)*
PARENT_CATEGORY_ID:  (this joins with CATEGORY_ID)
CATEGORY_ID: 10 (unique identifier for each category)

**This is what I am currently working with**, and just getting error after error. Last error saying PRODUCT_ID field does not exist, but I am certain it is exactly there. Hope to get a new set of eyes on this...

```
$db->query="SELECT count(a.PRODUCT_ID), 

    a.PRODUCT_ID,
    a.TITLE 

    FROM 

    PRD_PRODUCTS AS a, 
    PRD_CATEGORIES AS b

    LEFT JOIN PRD_PRODUCTS ON a.PRODUCT_ID = b.PRODUCT_ID

    LEFT JOIN PRD_CATEGORIES ON b.CATEGORY_ID = c.CATEGORY_ID 

WHERE a.SHOW_ON = 'A' 

GROUP BY a.PRODUCT_ID

ORDER BY a.TITLE DESC";
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Aren't you just looking for something like this?

```
SELECT CATEGORY_ID, COUNT(PRODUCT_ID) AS product_count
  FROM PRD_CATEGORIES
  GROUP BY CATEGORY_ID
```

UPDATE with filter:

```
SELECT pc.CATEGORY_ID, COUNT(pc.PRODUCT_ID) AS product_count
  FROM PRD_CATEGORIES pc
      ,PRD_PRODUCTS p
  WHERE pc.PRODUCT_ID = p.PRODUCT_ID
    AND p.SHOW_ON = 'A'
  GROUP BY CATEGORY_ID
```

Comment: Hi Glenn, I think this might actually solve a part of my problem, but I also need to filter the products by WHERE SHOW_ON = 'A' - SHOW_ON being in the PRD_PRODUCTS table.

Comment: I can finally rest my head... This one got me back on track. I had a to make a few adjustments for my tables, but it solved the problem.

Answer (score 0):

No, he needs to join the two tables together to know which products are in which category. I'm not sure why the original code joins twice though? If I understand what he is trying to do then he should just join the product id's to the categories (or vice versa) and then take the count of distinct product ids... right?

Also the group by needs to change to group by category since that is what you are trying to sum by...

```
SELECT 
     b.TITLE 
    ,count(distinct a.PRODUCT_ID)
 from PRD_PRODUCTS a
 left join  PRD_CATEGORIES b on b ON a.PRODUCT_ID = b.PRODUCT_ID
GROUP BY b.TITLE
```

Comment: "A count of all products for each category" would only need the PRD_CATEGORIES table for the count -if- each category was assured to be used by a product. But there seems to be too much missing info here: there is no CATEGORY table, the proposed query is referring to columns not in the table definitions and is retrieving columns that are not part of the question. So I'm not quite sure what is really being asked :)

Comment: I appreciate the suggestion, but I continue to run into this type of problem: Warning: 
Function : runQuery
Cause : You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'ON a.PRODUCT_ID = b.PRODUCT_ID GROUP BY b.TITLE' at line 3
Query : SELECT b.TITLE,count(distinct a.PRODUCT_ID) from PRD_PRODUCTS a left join PRD_CATEGORIES b on b ON a.PRODUCT_ID = b.PRODUCT_ID GROUP BY b.TITLE;

Comment: Server: Localhost via UNIX socket
Server version: 5.5.21-55